# How to toggle autohidden taskbar in Windows 11 without relaunching explorer.exe?

Tags: winapi, taskbar, windows-11

I am facing an issue with showing the taskbar during the lifetime of my app. On Windows 10, I was able to send the [ABM_SETSTATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/abm-setstate)  message via [SHAppBarMessage()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shappbarmessage) function with 0 to turn off the autohide. However, on Windows 11, the taskbar blinks for a moment and then hides again.

I have found a workaround to change the autohide parameter in the registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects3), but to apply the setting it requires relaunching explorer.exe, which is not suitable for my situation.

Comment: Have you tried broadcasting `WM_SETTINGSCHANGE` using `SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, ...)`?

Comment: Thank you. I've tried this method but it didn't worked for me.

After changing `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects3` autohide hex parameter to disabled state and calling a function 
`pabd.lParam = settings;`
`SHAppBarMessage(ABM_SETSTATE, &pabd);`

I called next function : `SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, LPARAM("StuckRects3"), 10, 0, &res);` but appbar didn't show up.

Comment: Try setting `ABS_ALWAYSONTOP` (the default, since Windows 7). If that doesn't work then you have to ask Microsoft to fix their implementation. Neither `ABM_SETSTATE` nor `SHAppBarMessage` are documented to not be supported on Windows 11. Though, knowing Microsoft, instead of fixing the implementation what they'll do is retroactively change the rules (i.e. the documentation).

Comment: I've tried `ABS_ALWAYSONTOP`, but nothing changed. Ok, I will try to clarify the solution to the problem with Microsoft.

Comment: Are you calling this from a Console application, a Windows Forms application or a WPF application? This works for me in Windows Forms, but not WPF https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76010249/calling-shappbarmessage-to-set-the-taskbar-works-from-applicationcontext-but-not

Comment: [I reproduced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1230347/hidden-taskbar-function-is-out-of-work-by-using-sh) and after consulting, you can open an incident about the concern at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support/. In-addition, if the support engineer determines that the issue is the result of a bug the service request will be a no-charge case and you won't be charged. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 11 it is now `System_TrayWnd`

```
public static IntPtr Handle
{
    get
    {
        return FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");
    }
}
```

Needs to be

```
public void SetTaskbarState(AppBarStates option)
{
    APPBARDATA msgData = new APPBARDATA();
    msgData.cbSize = (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(msgData);
    msgData.hWnd = Handle;
    msgData.lParam = (Int32)(option);
    SHAppBarMessage((UInt32)AppBarMessages.SetState, ref msgData);
}

public static IntPtr Handle
{
    get
    {
        return FindWindow("System_TrayWnd", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is not in finding the window, I've searched the taskbar window by it's window class name which is `Shell_TrayWnd`, that I've found in Inspect.exe tool.

Also the `System_TrayWnd` isn't look like a new name of the taskbar window class. Mentions of this name found on forums since 2003 or even sooner, so I guess it's an old class name. Being consistent I still tried your solution but it didn't result in any success.