# Calling SHAppBarMessage to set the taskbar works from ApplicationContext but not from WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have the following code to set the taskbar to auto hide using Interop.

```
public void SetTaskbarState(AppBarStates option)
{
    APPBARDATA msgData = new APPBARDATA();
    msgData.cbSize = (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(msgData);
    msgData.hWnd = Handle;
    msgData.lParam = (Int32)(option);
    SHAppBarMessage((UInt32)AppBarMessages.SetState, ref msgData);
}

public static IntPtr Handle
{
    get
    {
        return FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");
    }
}
```

I have an old WinForms application where I have a class that inherits from `ApplicationContext`. I am calling `SetTaskbarState` from the constructor of that class

```
public class MyContext : ApplicationContext
{
    public MyContext() 
    {
        SetTaskbarState(AppBarStates.AutoHide);
    }
}
```

The above works flawlessly and hides the taskbar.

In my WPF application that I am migrating to, I have a class called `App` that inherits from `System.Windows.Application`.

I have tried calling the same in the constructor, in the `OnStartup` method, and `OnLoadCompleted` method. No matter what it does not hide the taskbar like it does in the WinForms application.

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    // verified this is true but also have removed the if
    if (Settings.Instance.UI.HideTaskbar == true)
    {
        _taskbar.SetTaskbarState(AppBarStates.AutoHide);
    }

    base.OnStartup(e);

    // i have also tried calling it here
}
```

How can I hide the taskbar properly from within a WPF app?

EDIT: I verified that the call to Handle in both cases returns the same value.

[image: windws version]

Comment: What is your actual code in WPF?

Comment: Like literally it is just the same call to SetTaskbarState(AppBarStates.AutoHide) which I have tried in the constructor or OnStartup or OnLoadCompleted. Which one of those would you like to see an example of, if it helps?

Comment: Especially Handle. But why don't you post minimal reproducible example? It won't be long.

Comment: No worries I'll get that up tomorrow appreciate the look

Comment: I remember that the OS version matters because Microsoft modified taskbar at the rerent release of Windows 11 and so some of hacks for taskbar old days might no longer work.

Comment: It's just odd to me because the winforms one still works fine. Recompiled on same windows version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75977291/how-to-toggle-autohidden-taskbar-in-windows-11-without-relaunching-explorer-exe

Comment: I don't agree that it is broken in Windows 11. I have a Window Forms app that I call WM_SETSTATE on and it works great 100% of the time.

Comment: I tested my code capturing Shell_TrayWnd and making taskbar autohide on Windows 11 22H2 22624.1610 from a WinForms app and confirmed that it did not change taskbar. To be accurate, taskbar hid for a moment but return. That code worked as expected on Windows 10. Since you haven't posted a complete set of code, I could not reproduce exactly what you did. Have a good day.

Comment: Thanks @emoacht through your persistence that I was wrong, I got it working. It made me slim down my app as I know it was working, and sure enough it didn't work. I then found a reference to System_TrayWnd and reeplaced it with that and now auto hide works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows 11 it is now `System_TrayWnd`

```
public static IntPtr Handle
{
    get
    {
        return FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");
    }
}
```

Needs to be

```
public static IntPtr Handle
{
    get
    {
        return FindWindow("System_TrayWnd", "");
    }
}
```